# object inheritance virtual function run fail error

Tags: c++, object, inheritance, polymorphism, virtual

```
Shape *shape[100];//global scope
Square sqr;//global scope


void inputdata() {
int len,width;
cout << "enter length";
cin >> len;
cout << "enter width";
cin >> width;

Square sqr(len,width);
shape[0] = &sqr;
//----> if shape[0]->computeArea(); here works fine.
}

void computeArea() {
shape[0]->computeArea(); // --> run fail error
}
```

Shape is the parent class and square is the sub-class. both have computeArea();

when the code reach computeArea() i am having a weird run fail error. the program just terminate without giving me any errors for me to find and fix it...it just show run fail and stop the program.

the program is able to run properly and show ->computeArea() if the code is within the inputdata() but when i separate it, it just fail to run properly. any solution to this?

Comment: From the code you've posted, I don't see a problem, you probably have wrong things elsewhere.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This `Square`

```
Square sqr(len,width);
```

is an instance which is local to the scope of `inputdata`. Once you leave that scope, you are left with a dangling pointer in `shape[0]`. If you want to set the global `sqr`, you need

```
sqr = Square(len,width);
```

You should find a solution that doesn't rely on global variables though.

Answer (score 1):

`Square sqr(len, width)` creates an auto object. It goes away when the function returns, even though its address has been stored in `shape[0]`.

Answer (score 0):

change your code this way:

```
Shape *shape[100];//global scope
Square *sqr;//global scope  //make it a pointer or reference


void inputdata() {
int len,width;
cout << "enter length";
cin >> len;
cout << "enter width";
cin >> width;
sqr = new Square(len,width);
shape[0] = sqr;   //remove & here
}
void computeArea() {
shape[0]->computeArea(); 
}
```

Comment: There's no need for this dynamic allocation.

Comment: @juanchopanza What's the problem in dynamic allocation?

Comment: There is no need for it, so why use it? Now you have a resource you need to keep track of and delete.

Comment: @juanchopanza okay got it. _Keeping track of it and deleting it_ convinces me.